# MyBatis performance - access mappers

Tags: java, mybatis

I'm using MyBatis in a project that fetches many rows (more than 2M rows).

I have a simple question about how MyBatis works. Everytime I need an action from the mapper, does MyBatis read the XML file and extract the query? Or are the mappers put into memory and MyBatis access them directly?

This is important, because access and read a XML file can have impact on the performance values we are expecting.

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shortly, MyBatis parses the XML file when you first build your `SqlSessionFactory` from the configuration XML file. All the properties, mappers and settings are stored **in-memory** after that.

*Explanation:*
As stated in the doc, you can set up your `SqlSessionFactory` without XML, directly in Java as follows (see, last line):

```
DataSource dataSource = BlogDataSourceFactory.getBlogDataSource();
TransactionFactory transactionFactory = new JdbcTransactionFactory();
Environment environment = new Environment("development", transactionFactory, dataSource);
Configuration configuration = new Configuration(environment);
configuration.addMapper(BlogMapper.class);
SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(configuration);
```

Actually, when you build your `SqlSessionFactory` from XML, you will write something like this:

```
String resource = "org/mybatis/example/mybatis-config.xml";
InputStream inputStream = Resources.getResourceAsStream(resource);
SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(inputStream);
```

If you trace the source in `SqlSessionFactoryBuilder`,

```
  public SqlSessionFactory build(Reader reader, String environment, Properties properties) {
    try {
      XMLConfigBuilder parser = new XMLConfigBuilder(reader, environment, properties);
      return build(parser.parse());
 ...
```

The `parse()` method returns `Configuration` object, which holds all the information you supplied in the XML file.

```
public class Configuration {

  protected Environment environment;

  protected boolean safeRowBoundsEnabled = false;
  protected boolean safeResultHandlerEnabled = true;
  protected boolean mapUnderscoreToCamelCase = false;
  protected boolean aggressiveLazyLoading = true;
  protected boolean multipleResultSetsEnabled = true;
  protected boolean useGeneratedKeys = false;
  protected boolean useColumnLabel = true;
  protected boolean cacheEnabled = true;
  protected boolean callSettersOnNulls = false;
  protected String logPrefix;
  protected Class <? extends Log> logImpl;
  protected LocalCacheScope localCacheScope = LocalCacheScope.SESSION;
  protected JdbcType jdbcTypeForNull = JdbcType.OTHER;
  protected Set<String> lazyLoadTriggerMethods = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "equals", "clone", "hashCode", "toString" }));
  protected Integer defaultStatementTimeout;
  protected ExecutorType defaultExecutorType = ExecutorType.SIMPLE;
  protected AutoMappingBehavior autoMappingBehavior = AutoMappingBehavior.PARTIAL;

  protected Properties variables = new Properties();
  protected ObjectFactory objectFactory = new DefaultObjectFactory();
  protected ObjectWrapperFactory objectWrapperFactory = new DefaultObjectWrapperFactory();
  protected MapperRegistry mapperRegistry = new MapperRegistry(this);

  protected boolean lazyLoadingEnabled = false;
  protected ProxyFactory proxyFactory;

  protected String databaseId;
  /**
   * Configuration factory class.
   * Used to create Configuration for loading deserialized unread properties.
   *
   * @see <a href='https://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=300'>Issue 300</a> (google code)
   */
  protected Class<?> configurationFactory;

  protected final InterceptorChain interceptorChain = new InterceptorChain();
  protected final TypeHandlerRegistry typeHandlerRegistry = new TypeHandlerRegistry();
  protected final TypeAliasRegistry typeAliasRegistry = new TypeAliasRegistry();
  protected final LanguageDriverRegistry languageRegistry = new LanguageDriverRegistry();

  protected final Map<String, MappedStatement> mappedStatements = new StrictMap<MappedStatement>("Mapped Statements collection");
  protected final Map<String, Cache> caches = new StrictMap<Cache>("Caches collection");
  protected final Map<String, ResultMap> resultMaps = new StrictMap<ResultMap>("Result Maps collection");
  protected final Map<String, ParameterMap> parameterMaps = new StrictMap<ParameterMap>("Parameter Maps collection");
  protected final Map<String, KeyGenerator> keyGenerators = new StrictMap<KeyGenerator>("Key Generators collection");

  protected final Set<String> loadedResources = new HashSet<String>();
  protected final Map<String, XNode> sqlFragments = new StrictMap<XNode>("XML fragments parsed from previous mappers");

  protected final Collection<XMLStatementBuilder> incompleteStatements = new LinkedList<XMLStatementBuilder>();
  protected final Collection<CacheRefResolver> incompleteCacheRefs = new LinkedList<CacheRefResolver>();
  protected final Collection<ResultMapResolver> incompleteResultMaps = new LinkedList<ResultMapResolver>();
  protected final Collection<MethodResolver> incompleteMethods = new LinkedList<MethodResolver>();
...
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation. Exactly what I neeeded

Answer (score 0):

Just don't worry about this.
After setup, MyBatis parsed mapper xml to a local variable(xml file read at first time).
`org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.mappedStatements`.

Now, you invoke mapper.add()/sqlSession.selectOne() or others, it will get this parameter/resultMap/resultType from `mappedStatements` firstly , won't read xml again.

Also, MyBatis cached the mapper proxy method. like this(create proxy method instance first time you invoke)

```
final String resource = "org/apache/ibatis/builder/MapperConfig.xml";
final Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);
manager = SqlSessionManager.newInstance(reader);
AuthorMapper mapper = manager.getMapper(AuthorMapper.class);
Author expected = new Author(500, "cbegin", "******", "cbegin@somewhere.com", "Something...", null);
mapper.insertAuthor(expected);
```

(how to get mapper)

```
public class MapperRegistry {
public <T> T getMapper(Class<T> type, SqlSession sqlSession) {
    final MapperProxyFactory<T> mapperProxyFactory = (MapperProxyFactory<T>) knownMappers.get(type);
    if (mapperProxyFactory == null) {
        throw new BindingException("Type " + type + " is not known to the MapperRegistry.");
    }
    try {
        return mapperProxyFactory.newInstance(sqlSession);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BindingException("Error getting mapper instance. Cause: " + e, e);
    }
}
}
```

And, u can use query cache in mybatis 3.x+. Following this

```
<configuration>
  <settings>
    <setting name="cacheEnabled" value="true" />
  <settings>
</configuration>
```